# How to solve wpf treeview memory consumption?

Tags: wpf, memory, treeview

I have an app that loads all xml tags in a treeview for displaying?Problem is that my xml contain thousands of tags and eats a lot of memory.I read on internet that is a bug of wpf treeview .Can someone help me ?

Comment: Assuming your not loading thousands of root level nodes, research "lazy loading".  Then you only load the levels that need to be shown/expanded.  You should also look at WPF virtualization.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Actually, a much more sensible option would be to load only a subset of data in memory. Data virtualization is a standard trick for grids and any control that has to display a lot of data, since the VB6 days (and earlier).

Comment: @Panagiotis, yup, I know that. This is a good solution for lists controls (e.g. the "virtual mode" of the standard listview control). It's less useful with trees, though, because the user only has to hit "Expand All" and you're back to square one.

Answer (score 3):

The WPF TreeView control *already* provides a form of data virtualization, as described in [How to: Improve the Performance of a TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716882(v=vs.110).aspx). This addresses displaying a lot of data that is already held in memory.

Essentially, you add the [VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.isvirtualizing(v=vs.110).aspx) and [VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.virtualizationmode(v=vs.110).aspx) attached properties to your Treeview. The virtualizing stack panel only creates and binds the items that are visible on screen:

```
<TreeView Height="200" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataItems}}"
        VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
        VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
```

This doesn't address the scenario where you've loaded many thousands of records in memory. In this case it would be the source data that caused the problem, not the TreeView itself. The real solution in this case would be to *not* load so many items in the first place, by using proper filters. Another option would be to load the data in pages whenever the user scrolls too far down.

Yet another option is loading child nodes when the user expands a parent node, although this would introduce an annoying delay.

Comment: Hi , I tried your code but same probleme occur , it seems virtualization is not working.

Comment: The Virtualizing stack panel does work but it won't solve the problem of loading thousands of items when you don't need to. It solves the problem of creating thousands of treeview nodes even if they don't get displayed. Also, it works *only* if you use databinding. If you add the nodes manually, you've already bypassed it. You need to post the treeview's XAML and the code used to load and bind the items

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, actually `Virtualizing` works if I load thousands of items in TreeView. Without `Virtualizing` my application had weight about 700 mb, with `Virtualizing` it became about 70-80 mb. So, it really works.